# How to make responsive this code

Tags: css, responsive-design

my problem is this code that does not work when I make it responsive.. I know to change height and width must transform in percentage but this code is damaged when I make it responsive ..

**This code *Css ( which I want to transform it into responsive ) :**

```
    @import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo);

/* entypo */
[class*="entypo-"]:before {
  font-family: 'entypo', sans-serif;
}




.entry{
  width:430px;
  position: RELATIVE;
  top:600PX;
  LEFT: 5PX;
  margin:50px auto;
  border-radius:50%;
  float:left;

}


.container{
  width:110px;
  height:110px;
  margin:0 0 30px 10px;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:60px;  
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  box-shadow:3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);  
  transition:all .5s;
  overflow:hidden;

}

.photo{
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
  margin:8px;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  overflow:hidden;  
  border:2px solid white;
}

.pic{ max-width:100%; }

.button{  
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  top:25px;
  font-size:40px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:60px;
  border-radius:50%;  
  color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);  
  background:green; 
  background:linear-gradient(bottom,#5ca321,#8ab24f);
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
             0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,.1),
             0 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transition:all .5s;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.button:hover{
  background:#5ca321;
  box-shadow:inset 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  text-shadow:0px 0px 5px gray;
}

.name{

  height:60%;
  width:180px;
  position:absolute;
  right:80px;
  padding:20px;
  font:25px arial;
  color:white;  
  opacity:0;
  transition:all .5s .5s;
  text-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.small{ font-size:14px; display:block; margin-top:10px; }

.comment{
  width:370px;
  position:relative;
  padding:15px;
  font-size:16px;
  color:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  border-radius:10px;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.4);
  box-shadow:3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  opacity:0;
  transition:all 1s;
}

.comment:before{
  content:'';
  width:0;
  height:0;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:100%;
  left:2%;
  border-bottom:15px solid rgba(255,255,255,.4);
  border-left:50px solid transparent;
  border-right:50px solid transparent;
  border-top:15px solid transparent;

}

.container:hover{ width:400px; }

.container:hover .name,.container:hover + .comment{
  opacity:1;
}
```

**Maybe you need look demo** 
https://codepen.io/GARDFIELD3/pen/zNgmMP
**I want to do this responsive that  size and position** Thank and ignore my mistakes of speech but i I do not speak English :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 2):

It's not responsive because you don't have media queries in your CSS. As of right now, your code will run regardless of screen size, but let's say you wanted to look differently on a mobile phone, then you would do something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {

    /* put in different CSS code here */

}
```

Comment: so if add this code in css will become receptive without changing anything? I'm a beginner say me more please :) i want to make receptive for all device :)

Comment: You will have to write new code because you're using absolute pixel sizes which doesn't give you much flexibility. For example, your `.entry` has a hard width of 430 pixels, but that's clearly bigger than a phone screen that's around 420 pixels, so you're going to have content hanging off the edge which would give you a side scrolling bar and nobody wants that.  Had you used percents instead, you might have been able to get away with not changing much, but because you didn't...you'll have to write new code.

Comment: well I can not to modify for make responsive without making a new one ? How to transform those pixels in percentage?

Comment: You do not think that you could turn into responsive code? I would be grateful :)

Comment: You don't have to turn it into into percentages at this point, you could just rewrite the parts that appear broken at a smaller size. Because you didn't design this with other devices in mind, what I would do is resize your browser down to the smallest device size, see what's looking bad, then write the CSS for those things, moving all the way up until you're back at a full desktop width. I don't think you can get around from writing a bunch of new code. And you're only writing it for media queries that target certain sizes, you're not redoing the entire thing.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I didn't understand anything .. I understand from examples , too much theory ..too little practice :)  if you edit code maybe so do I understood .. respect for your time in which you tried to help me...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use media queries and target whichever element you want to change.

For example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
 .entry {
  margin-top: 100px;
 }
}
```

This will add a margin-top of 100px to your `.entry` class for screens with a width equal to or bigger than 767px.

[Read more/take a tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) as an introduction.

Comment: please edit for me code for  because I understand only concrete examples  , allow time for me please and help me ..

Answer (score 0):

Is this closer to what you want to achieve?

I've set the width of `comment` and `entry` to 100% because you probably want both div-tags to expand to the full width of the document.

Though it's true that the width will be relative to the document, this doesn't mean that any of this is `responsive design`. Responsive design keeps the `viewport` in regard. Try googling that. It's highly unlikely that there are no tutorials available in your language.

```css
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo);
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
/* entypo */}
[class*="entypo-"]:before {
  font-family: 'entypo', sans-serif;
}




.entry{
  width:100%;
  position: RELATIVE;
  top:60PX;
  LEFT: 5PX;
  margin:50px auto;
  border-radius:50%;
  float:left;

}


.container{
  position:relative;
  width:110px;
  height:110px;
  margin:0 0 30px 10px;
  
  border-radius:60px;  
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  box-shadow:3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);  
  
  transition:all .5s;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.photo{
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
  margin:8px;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  overflow:hidden;  
  border:2px solid white;
}

.pic{ max-width:100%; }

.button{  
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  top:25px;
  font-size:40px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:60px;
  border-radius:50%;  
  color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);  
  background:green; 
  background:linear-gradient(bottom,#5ca321,#8ab24f);
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
             0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,.1),
             0 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transition:all .5s;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.button:hover{
  background:#5ca321;
  box-shadow:inset 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  text-shadow:0px 0px 5px gray;
}

.name{
  
  height:60%;
  width:180px;
  position:absolute;
  right:80px;
  padding:20px;
  font:25px arial;
  color:white;  
  opacity:0;
  transition:all .5s .5s;
  text-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.small{ font-size:14px; display:block; margin-top:10px; }

.comment{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  padding:15px;
  font-size:16px;
  color:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  border-radius:10px;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.4);
  box-shadow:3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  opacity:0;
  transition:all 1s;
}

.comment:before{
  content:'';
  width:0;
  height:0;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:100%;
  left:2%;
  border-bottom:15px solid rgba(255,255,255,.4);
  border-left:50px solid transparent;
  border-right:50px solid transparent;
  border-top:15px solid transparent;
  
}

.container:hover{ width:100%; }

.container:hover .name,.container:hover + .comment{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
  
  <div class="container">    
    <div class="button entypo-chat"></div>
    <div class="name">CoStY
      <span class="small">Fondator</span>      
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="https://s12.postimg.org/pptidy8kd/14021445_1166695373388266_6290547632102759142_n.jpg" alt="" class="pic">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <p class="comment">Salut, numele meu este Enache Constantin si sunt creatorul acestei comunitati :) Puteti sa ajutati la intretinerea comunitatii printr-o donatie ,pm pentru detalii :) </p>
  
</div>

<div class="entry">
  
  <div class="container">    
    <div class="button entypo-chat"></div>
    <div class="name">Gardfield<3
      <span class="small">Administrator</span>      
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/133/378977890_40f31e1962_q.jpg" alt="" class="pic">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <p class="comment">Salut,numele meu este Alexandru Mihai iar misiunea mea este sa dezvolt aceasta comunitate din toate punctele de vedere. Sunt deschis la orice colaborare si ma puteti contacta pentru probleme tehnice printr-un pm :)  </p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Yes close to the truth that position but not as size .. I want to see well on any resolution .. You think you can do that please?i`m too beginner I understand how I can do this

Comment: I'm afraid what you are asking is too broad for one answer. Can't you find any documentation in your language? For example [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp). Click the globe icon (right hand corner) to translate into romanian :)

Comment: I respect you , thou hast made responsive position but i want to change size in responsive .. transform widht , height in procent I think that would make responsive size .. you understand what I'm looking , if you do that you'll hear winner ..